# Setting application log level in TestNG

Tags: java, testng

I have an application that uses Commons Logging for logging. It's built with Maven, and uses TestNG for testing.

I'm trying to fine-tune the logging level during tests, but not having any luck - everything is set to INFO, no matter what I do.

I tried creating a `logging.properties` file on the classpath, and it does absolutely nothing. I also created a `log4testng.properties` file - this one is being read (I know this because TestNG showed an error after I deliberately introduced a syntax error into it) but the settings in it have no effect.

Any suggestions?

---

EDIT: I haven't figured out the underlying problem (why `java.util.logging` is ignoring my attempts to configure it) but I was able to get what I want by making Log4j available during tests, then configuring that.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround for this.  Create your custom logging.properties in src/test/resources, then in a setup call, load it up as such:

```
@BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
protected void setUp() throws SecurityException, IOException
{
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(BaseRestTest.class.getResource("/logging.properties").getFile());
    LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(fis);
}
```

This appears to re-configure the root logger after TestNG has pillaged it.

Answer (score -1):

Mike,

You can adjust the log level in testng.xml:

```
<suite verbose="3"...  (up to 10)
```

TestNG doesn't use Log4J nor java.util.logging.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I don't care about TestNG's log output; I care about my application's output.

Comment: Why doesn't TestNG use java.util.properties? That seems pretty silly to me. Using a logging.properties file to configure the java.util.logger class is a widely-accepted standard for the Java language, and TestNG is completely ignoring this.

Comment: TestNG has its own completely awesome Reporter class.  If you need additionaly file logging, you can add Log4j to your project with a FileAppender, otherwise the Reporter logger is just fine for report and console output.  By the way the "verbose" TestNG option only makes sense if you actually log Reporter.log statements with the log level argument included (with each one), right?